# How to use Distinct in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query to count the number of presents employee have in a month.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COUNT([Attendance].[Status])
FROM
    [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance] [Attendance], [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info]
WHERE 
    [Attendance].[Status] IN ('Early Left', 'Present', 'Half Day', 'Late In')
    AND [Info].[ID] = [Attendance].[EmpCode] 
    AND [Attendance].[EmpCode] = 266 
    AND CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS DATE) >= '2018-08-01' 
    AND CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeOut] AS DATE) <= '2018-08-15'
```

Now there are plenty of employees that have been marked there attendance twice or thrice in one date. Like once an employee leave his attendance is placed as out and once he comes than as timein. So now on counting it is adding same days attendance multiple times. I want to get distinct dates between the dates.

Here is sample data:

```
2018-04-04 18:12:30  2018-04-04 19:38:12   266  Present
2018-04-04 09:43:01  2018-04-04 09:58:41   266  Present
2018-04-05 16:40:52  2018-04-05 18:40:52   266  Present
2018-04-06 11:35:59  2018-04-06 11:48:49   266  Present
```

Now it is counting date 4 two times but it should count it single time.

Comment: It is time to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around more than 25 years now. Comma separated lists of tables is just awful for a number of reasons. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to cast to date and perform the distinct

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] as Date))
FROM [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance] [Attendance], [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info]
WHERE [Attendance].[Status] IN ('Early Left', 'Present', 'Half Day', 'Late In')
AND [Info].[ID] = [Attendance].[EmpCode] AND [Attendance].[EmpCode] = 266 
AND CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS DATE) >= '2018-08-01' 
AND CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeOut] AS DATE) <= '2018-08-15'
```

Answer (score 3):

`DISTINCT` should be inside the `COUNT()`

So, it would be :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Attendance].[Status]), 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS Date))
. . .
```

However, i would suggest to use proper standard, explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of comma in `FROM` clause :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Attendance].[Status]),
       COUNT(DISTINCT CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS Date))
FROM [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeAttendance] [Attendance] INNER JOIN
     [HRM].[tbl_EmployeeInfo] [Info]
     ON [Info].[ID] = [Attendance].[EmpCode] 
WHERE [Attendance].[Status] IN ('Early Left', 'Present', 'Half Day', 'Late In') AND 
      [Attendance].[EmpCode] = 266 AND 
      CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeIn] AS DATE) >= '2018-08-01'AND 
      CAST([Attendance].[AttendanceTimeOut] AS DATE) <= '2018-08-15'
```

Comment: There is only 1 status, I don't think they want Distinct Status

Comment: Yes I want Distinct Date